# How do I make pandas read_csv ignore separator between partially quoted values?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I make `read_csv` ignore the separator between the double quotes, i.e., ignore the `,` inside `key:"2,3"`.

Using Python 3.7.4, I have tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
key:"1",value:"a"
key:"2,3",value:"b"
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=None, names=['key', 'value'])

print(df)
```

This code gives me the following output:

```
       key      value
0  key:"1"  value:"a"
1   key:"2         3"
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
         key      value
0    key:"1"  value:"a"
1  key:"2,3"  value:"b"
```

Comment: do you really want e.g., "key" and "value" to be in the dataframe elements?

Comment: That's not a CSV.  What generated that?  You would have more luck changing whatever generated this to either generate a real CSV (`key,value` / `1,a` / `"2,3",b`), or make it generate JSON, which this almost is.

Comment: Yes, I want "key" and "value" to be in the dataframe elements. In the "real" data, the "key" and "value" have different names.

Comment: I can't change how the data is generated. I can parse each row using other means, but it would be nice if I could use pandas `read_csv`.

Comment: I'd love to know more about how you plan to use this dataframe. I can't (currently) imagine a scenario where a dataframe constructed this way could be effectively used.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this with `read_csv` you can do it by using `sep='",'`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
key:"1",value:"a"
key:"2,3",value:"b"
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=None, sep='",', names=['key', 'value'], engine='python')
df['key'] = df['key'] + '"'
```

Result:

|  | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | key:"1" | value:"a" |
| 1 | key:"2,3" | value:"b" |